# Adding Props to found components throw the mounted wrapper

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils, vue-testing-library, vitest

I have a form that contains a selector reusable component like this

```
<template>
  <div class="channelDetail" data-test="channelDetail">
    <div class="row">
      <BaseTypography class="label">{{ t('channel.detail.service') }}</BaseTypography>
      <BaseSelector
        v-model="serviceId"
        data-test="serviceInput"
        class="content"
        :option="servicePicker.data?.data"
        :class="serviceIdErrorMessage && 'input-error'"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <BaseTypography class="label">{{ t('channel.detail.title') }}</BaseTypography>
      <BaseInput v-model="title" data-test="titleInput" class="content" :class="titleErrorMessage && 'input-error'" />
     </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

I'm going to **test** this form by using **vue-test-utils** and **vitest**.
I need to set option props from the script to the selector.
In my thought, this should be worked but not

```
it('test', async () => {
  const wrapper=mount(MyForm,{})
  wrapper.findComponent(BaseSelector).setProps({option:[...some options]})
   ---or
  wrapper.find('[data-test="serviceInput"]').setProps({option:[...some options]})
   ---or ???
});
```

***Could anyone help me to set the props into components in the mounted wrapper component?***

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you should not do that. Because `BaseSelector` should have it's own tests in which you should test behavior changes through the `setProps`.

But if you can't do this for some reason, here what you can do:

1. Check the props passed to `BaseSelector`. They always depend on some reactive data (`props`, `data`, or `computed`)
2. Change those data in `MyForm` instead.

For example

```
// MyForm.vue
data() {
  return {
    servicePicker: {data: null}
  }
}

// test.js
wrapper = mount(MyForm)
wrapper.setData({servicePicker: {data: [...some data]})
expect(wrapper.findComponent(BaseSelector)).toDoSomething()
```

But I suggest you to cover the behavior of `BaseSelector` in separate test by changing it's props or data. And then in the `MyForm`'s test you should just check the passed props to `BaseSelector`

```
expect(wrapper.findComponent(BaseSelector).props('options')).toEqual(expected)
```